# First Barren Woman to Bear Children

Tags: parsha-torah-portion, parshanut-torah-comment, riddle, minor-katan-child

Who was the first *akarah* (barren woman) in the Torah to bear **children**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lemech'2nd wife, Tzilah, was supposedly barren from drinking the kos shel akarim.  Nevertheless, she gave birth to Tuval Kayin, and Naamah.

Comment: I do not know if this answer is correct, as I would think the question is Who was the first natural Akarah to bear children.

Comment: I said Akarah, meaning in general, natural or not. This is exactly the correct answer!

Comment: Not 2'nd wife, but one of his wifes. since there are two opinions which of them was for פריה ורביה and which for other purpose.